# API grabber not working/displaying wrong output

Tags: python, discord.py

So im working on a discord.py bot for a game. The bot is meant to store every page of the auctions in a list, where I can then search for specific items in every one of those pages. My code is:

to get the list of apis:

```
apibaz = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=6c9b8b23-2d70-4b3d-a639-5276098b487a').json()

apiauc1 = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=6c9b8b23-2d70-4b3d-a639-5276098b487a&page=1').json()

leg = (apiauc1['totalPages'])

leg = leg-1

apiaucM = []

v = 1

while v != (leg):
    apiaucM.append(requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=6c9b8b23-2d70-4b3d-a639-5276098b487a&page=' + str(v)).json())
    v = v+1
```

`

To use the apis to find the prices of the items which are inputted:

```
if message.content.startswith('baz!bin'):
    await message.channel.send('finding...')
    y = 0
    z = 0
    listt = []
    brii = message.content.split(None, 1)[1]

    u = -1

    p = -1
    while p != (leg):
        p = p+1
        leng = len(apiaucM[0]['auctions'])
        while u != (leng-1):
            u = u+1
            if brii == (apiaucM[p]['auctions'][u]['item_name']):
                z = z+1
                print('yues')
                if 'bin' in (apiaucM[p]['auctions'][u]):
                    print('YES')
                    y = y+1
                    await message.channel.send('bin located')
                    cost = (apiaucM[p]['auctions'][u]['starting_bid'])
                    listt.append(cost)
                    print('b')

    print('c')
    x = 0
    o = 0
    lenp = len(listt)
    if lenp == 1:
        fcost = listt[0]
        x = 1

    for item in listt:
        print(item)
        if item > x:
            print('dd')
            x = 1
            fcost = item






    if z == 0:
        await message.channel.send("I couldn't find any auctions for that item. Maybe check that the id is correct." )

    elif x != 0:
        await message.channel.send('The lowest BIN I could find was for ' + str(fcost) + ' coins. There were a total of ' + str(y) + ' BINs.')
    else:
        await message.channel.send('Sorry, I couldnt find any bins for that item.')
```

If it only searches one page, which is what I think it might be doing, then it would only be searching through 1/40 of the auction house. The outputs are:

[Discord Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5PlZ.png)

[Shell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6eqD.png)

Any help on why this is happening is appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest a good start would be making your code a lot more readable, replacing your while loops with for loops since you know exactly how much data you have, and including some example input in you question.

Answer (score 0):

First let's clean up your code and make it nonblocking. The requests library isn't asynchronous and is therefor blocking. Instead you should use the aiohttp library (https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) which is asynchronous. Second of all, if you're making multiple requests you should make a Session, so you don't start a new one for each request.

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async with ClientSession() as session:  # Opens a session

    async with session.get(firsturl) as page:  # gets a page within the session
        apibaz = await page.json()  # assigns the json to the variable

    async with session.get(secondurl) as page:
        apiauc1 = await page.json()  # You should avoid using numbers in variables btw 

    pages = apibaz['totalPages']

    apiaucM = []

    for i in range(1, pages):
        async with session.get(f'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=6c9b8b23-2d70-4b3d-a639-5276098b487a&page={i}') as page:  # f strings are very useful, consider using them you can put a variable in a {} and it will be replaced by the string of the variable
            apiaucM.append(await page.json())
```

For the rest of your code you'll have to change it to be easier to read. Don't use while loops, use for loops and variable names should describe what they are not just be called u, p, y, z, ...
Try printing what it gets from the api and check if it's what you want.